# How to get rdf file from sparql endpoint

Tags: rdf, sparql, endpoint, opendata

I am new in opendata and need some help. Wikipedia have their sparql endpoint in this url:
http://dbpedia.org/sparql
Now I need to write webservice to get some rdf file from dbpedia. What should I send to this endpoint to get rdf file ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Send a [CONSTRUCT](http://www.w3.org/TR/rdf-sparql-query/#construct) query. A little example:

```
CONSTRUCT { ?s ?p ?o }
WHERE { ?s ?p ?o }
LIMIT 10
```

The WHERE clause works just like that of SELECT only the values fill the CONSTRUCT block as a kind of template. It's very flexible - you can either copy statements as here or transform them into a completely different shape.

Comment: can you write here sparql which return from dbpedia all rdf file where is mention something about berlin ?

Comment: @hudi It sounds like you are just starting out with SPARQL, have you tried reading one of the popular tutorials like http://www.cambridgesemantics.com/2008/09/sparql-by-example/ which explains it step by step?

Comment: yes I read this but still no understand sparql because in this example is just query and result but no describton of sparql query

Answer (score 4):

What Danny answered is the right generic answer. But I would not recommend you to perform such query over external services, due the time expected to get the result; do it over a concrete resource

But of course if you'd like to do it directly without the need of manually save the query results, with Python for instance the code would look like:

```
from SPARQLWrapper import SPARQLWrapper, XML

uri = "http://dbpedia.org/resource/Asturias"
query = "CONSTRUCT { <%s> ?p ?o } WHERE { <%s> ?p ?o }" % (uri, uri)

sparql = SPARQLWrapper("http://dbpedia.org/sparql")
sparql.setQuery(query)
sparql.setReturnFormat(XML)
results = sparql.query().convert()

file = open("output.rdf", "w")
results.serialize(destination=file, format="xml")
file.flush()
file.close()
```

Of course, this could be done with almost any programming language, as you prefer.

Comment: Which in any SPARQL 1.1 compliant implementation should be equivalent to a [DESCRIBE](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#describe) query: `DESCRIBE <http://dbpedia.org/resource/Asturias>`.

Comment: can i ask you one question about the rdf saving locally???  what is the different i just use results.serialize(destination=path , format="xml") ,,,, and use file=open(......."w").......file.close()... your answer help me solve the problem. but i would like to know the difference.

Answer (score 2):

I would like to recommend you reading Bob DuCharme's ["Learning SPARQL"](http://learningsparql.com/) book. It covers some examples that make use of the DBPedia endpoint as well.

PS: It's not Wikipedia's SPARQL endpoint - it's DBPedia SPARQL endpoint (Wikipedia itself doesn't provide an own SPARQL endpoint ATM). However, DBPedia data relies on Wikipedia data ;)